# Images in recycler view not staggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with staggeredgridlayout , i have set up everything as i'm getting all images from request api and what i noticed is that they all have the same size 700 * 700 which could be the reason behind the images not being staggered , they look more like gridview , not staggered ones ,
if anyone can help i'd deeply appreciate it ..

- This is my code

```
  staggeredGridLayoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        staggeredGridLayoutManager.gapStrategy =     StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS
        binding.subCountryrecycler.layoutManager = staggeredGridLayoutManager
        binding.subCountryrecycler.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        binding.subCountryrecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

*This is my adapter layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <data>

       <variable
           name="subcountryListener"
           type="taki.food.foodappv.listeners.SubGeneralListener" />

       <variable
           name="subCountry"
           type="taki.food.foodappv.models.SubCountriesModel" />
   </data>

   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
       app:cardElevation="8dp"
       android:layout_margin="10dp">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.mask.PorterShapeImageView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="155dp"
               app:siShape="@drawable/ic_cardbackground"
               app:subBinding="@{subCountry.strMealThumb}"
               app:siSquare="false"/>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
               android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
               android:text="@{subCountry.strMeal}"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:maxLines="1"
               android:id="@+id/name_widget"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
               android:textColor="#000"/>


       </LinearLayout>
   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</layout>
```

Comment: You should try  a couple of things: 
- remove this attribute: binding.subCountryrecycler.setHasFixedSize(true).
- change the width and height of the image to wrap_content;
- add to where you are loading the image, the attributes to min height or width.
Because the fact that all the images comes in 700 * 700 may be the reason wht they dont look staggered.

Comment: thank you for replying , i did so as well but it didnt seem to fix the issue , as i beleive the issue is because the images have the same size , or am i wrong ?

Comment: To prove that the problem is with the  700 * 700 size, you should add, for exemple, a text view to the card, with different words inside the text view, so the card should take different sizes, you know what I mean?

Comment: Exactly  , if  the textview has two or three lines , it would expand the layout and make it look like staggeredGridLayout but if my textviews have all max of 1 line , then it goes back to the same issue as before , that's what is happening with me now

Comment: So if you did that and the recycler view behaved as staggered, you can assume now that the issue is with the fact that all images have the same size. =)

Comment: I totally agree because if images have different sizes , the imageview will expand according to differet heights and widths , that way is way easier , but if all has the same size , there should  be some customization in the layout or something but  found nothing useful yet :(

Comment: what are you using to show the images? Picasso? Glide?

Comment: I'm using Picasso

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228282/discussion-between-taki-eddine-and-tarsila-costalonga).